# How do open my react native app on volume up or down button double press?

Tags: react-native

I want to open my react native application on any key phone's physical key press like volume up or low button, How can do this in react native.

Comment: I think this deppends on your phone, not your app

Comment: no i have seen some app they are using it for example 112 app of indian government has this feature.

Comment: if pressing the volume up, opens your app, how does the person using the phone will raise the volume?

Comment: I will set my app open scenario when the volume button is double pressed.